# Equivalent Encryption for MCRYPT - To preserve client side code

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I'm using the following code to perform encryption using mcrypt

```
<?PHP

    define('SECURE_KEY','Somekey');

    function encrypt($value){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SECURE_KEY, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    }

    function decrypt($value){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SECURE_KEY, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    }
    $temp=encrypt("teststring");
    printf($temp);
    ?>
```

The newer versions of php depreciates mcrypt,im looking for a replacement for the same that works with the same key and produces the same result,so that i dont need to change client side code.

Comment: I recommend you to change it. It is very old and nonstandard that is  `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not [AES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php). I suggest you use authenticated encryption modes as AES-GCM or ChaCha20Poly1305.

Comment: One of the big reason why mcrypt is being deprecated is because it promotes insecure encryption methods. If I look at your code, we have a key that's really a (short) password, ECB mode encryption (which actually doesn't use an IV) and zero padding which could strip of trailing zero bytes (although the `trim` function would otherwise do that). That's on top of the fact that you're not using AES, as kelalaka has already indicated. You need to establish a secure protocol and convert to that.

Comment: @kelalaka okay.. will do.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes okay.. will do.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of the RFC [to deprecate then remove mcrypt from PHP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral).

What you should absolutely do is migrate your data to use the new Sodium extension instead. [Learn how to get started with libsodium in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use#crypto-aead). The code examples are safe to use.

```
<?php
/**
 * Wrap crypto_aead_*_encrypt() in a drop-dead-simple encryption interface
 *
 * @link https://paragonie.com/b/kIqqEWlp3VUOpRD7
 * @param string $message
 * @param string $key
 * @return string
 */
function simpleEncrypt($message, $key)
{
    $nonce = random_bytes(24); // NONCE = Number to be used ONCE, for each message
    $encrypted = sodium_crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt(
        $message,
        $nonce,
        $nonce,
        $key
    );
    return $nonce . $encrypted;
}

/**
 * Wrap crypto_aead_*_decrypt() in a drop-dead-simple decryption interface
 *
 * @link https://paragonie.com/b/kIqqEWlp3VUOpRD7
 * @param string $message - Encrypted message
 * @param string $key     - Encryption key
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
function simpleDecrypt($message, $key)
{
    $nonce = mb_substr($message, 0, 24, '8bit');
    $ciphertext = mb_substr($message, 24, null, '8bit');
    $plaintext = sodium_crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(
        $ciphertext,
        $nonce,
        $nonce,
        $key
    );
    if (!is_string($plaintext)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid message');
    }
    return $plaintext;
}

$secretKey = random_bytes(32);
$message = 'Test message';

/* Encrypt the message: */
$ciphertext = simpleEncrypt($message, $secretKey);

/* Decrypt the message: */
try {
    $decrypted = simpleDecrypt($ciphertext, $secretKey);
    var_dump(hash_equals($decrypted, $message));
    /* bool(true) */
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    /* Someone is up to no good */
    exit(255);
}
```

If you need a "transition" step between PHP 7.1 and older, and PHP 7.2 and newer, [mcrypt_compat](https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat) is a polyfill library created by the phpseclib developers to facilitate migrations between mcrypt and non-abandonware libraries (OpenSSL, Sodium).

Only use it for migrations. Don't rely on it to "just work" and be secure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I upgraded the PHP version and used AES Encryption Scheme.